# Heroku zero-downtime deployment with Unicorn

Tags: heroku, unicorn

I was wondering if it's possible to have a zero-downtime deployment strategy with Heroku. I find with the current Heroku docs, that upon pushing an app, it takes about 1 minute to reload the app, which makes it unusable. The unicorn code in their documentation does preload the app, so I'm confused why this is happening. Is there anything I can do on my end?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

I have the new relic addon as well as bonsai for elastic search.

Here is my unicorn.rb initializer:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|

 Signal.trap 'TERM' do
   puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
   Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
 end

 defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end 

after_fork do |server, worker|

 Signal.trap 'TERM' do
   puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
 end

 defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: have you seen Heroku preboot in labs? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot/

Comment: I did not, and it looks great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2014-11-14:**

Preboot is now generally available (thanks @camJackson for the bump).

Changelog entry:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/544

New(ish) Dev Center article:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/544

---

*original reply*

The only current means to do this is with the pre-boot lab feature:

- [Heroku Labs: preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-preboot/)

Preboot is a **work in progress**.

Note that using Unicorn doesn't have any impact here. The preloading in that context is the master process preloading the Rails app before forking workers; this happens after the new dynos are spun up and cycled out.

Comment: Looks like preboot is properly released now: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot